# How to discard values in a python panda series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series with a buch of rows, some of the rows have values, the others have None.
I want to discard the None values and retain the others in a new series.

So far I have tried:

```
data.where(~(data == None))
data[data != None]
data[[i for i in data.index if i != None]]
```

Also I checked the filter method, but no success either.

But all of them return a series with the same number of rows than the initial one, incluiding the None values.

I need to discard the None values because I have not knowledge of which values are the ones different than None, and the list of values is over a thousand entryes and the mayority are None.

Comment: Are the values really None, or are they NaN?  Does `data.dropna()` work?

Comment: Can you give an example of a couple of rows of your data

Comment: The values are None, but that method worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally (ie for values that python doesnt see as NaN);

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '0123', 'e', 'f', 'g'])
a = a.loc[a != '0123']
print a
```

or

```
a = a[a != '0123']
```

Output:

```
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    d
5    e
6    f
7    g
```

I suspect you were trying to do the filtering in-place (ie not assigning the result to a variable) if those methods you tried didn't work.